# How can I run an async process in the background without popping up a buffer?

Tags: shell, async, process

I have defined some functions to run async background process using `async-shell-command` in my .emacs, but everytime I run the commands a new window (not frame) is created and the process' buffer is shown there. How could I run the command without the "pop up" buffer?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can start background processes with `start-process`, which shouldn't pop up a buffer:

```el
(start-process "process-name" "buffer-name" "program")
```

Process names are modified to avoid duplication as necessary, so don't worry about that. Just give it a name useful for debugging in the future!

If you give a `"buffer-name"`, a buffer will be created but not shown immediately. This can be convenient for managing processes and looking at output. If you don't want a buffer to be created at all, pass `nil` as the buffer name:

```el
(start-process "process-name" nil "program")
```

Comment: Is it possible to use `start-process` for a sudo command? I tried wrapping my call to `start-process` in `(let ((default-directory "/sudo::")) ... )` but it didn't work for me.

Comment: @sid-kap: I don't know. You should probably ask that as a standalone question.

Comment: `"program"` in this case is only program name (e.g nautilus, caja, firefox) and `"arg1 arg2 ..."` should be in the fourth positional argument of `start-process`. I figured that out by reading the documentation :)

Answer (score 8):

Like Tikhon mentioned, `(start-process)` is the way to go. In case you don't want to create a buffer but would still like to react to the background process status, you can also employ `(set-process-sentinel)`. Here's a modified example I'm taking from my [`projector`](https://github.com/waymondo/projector.el) package:

```el
(set-process-sentinel (start-process "process-name" nil "command") #'output-message-sentinel)

(defun output-message-sentinel (process msg)
  (when (memq (process-status process) '(exit signal))
    (message (concat (process-name process) " - " msg))))
```

From the Emacs function description:

```
(set-process-sentinel PROCESS SENTINEL)

Give PROCESS the sentinel SENTINEL; nil for default.
The sentinel is called as a function when the process changes state.
It gets two arguments: the process, and a string describing the change.
```

The [GNU manual pages on Processes](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Processes.html#Processes) is pretty good for more info.

Comment: Could you describe what `set-process-sentinel` does a bit more accurately? I get the general idea of having a function that manages the process, but I don't fully understand all the details. Thanks!

Comment: If you do `M-x describe-function` and enter `set-process-sentinel` you'll get the short answer from Emacs documentation:  

(set-process-sentinel PROCESS SENTINEL)  
 
Give PROCESS the sentinel SENTINEL; nil for default.
The sentinel is called as a function when the process changes state.
It gets two arguments: the process, and a string describing the change.

Comment: The [GNU Emacs manual pages on Sentinels](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Sentinels.html) and [Processes](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Processes.html#Processes) are actually pretty good for more detailed information.

Comment: Cool. Perhaps you could edit the links into your answer? I guess one could also learn more just using `C-h f`...

Answer (score 4):

There's no need to change how you run an asynchronous command. Emacs has a generic ability to allow you to control where or whether any buffer will pop-up, by modifying a single data structure, the `display-buffer-alist`.

In the solution below, you can see that the action function `display-buffer-no-window` (ie. no pop-up) is set to be associated with any buffer with a name beginning `*Asynchronous Shell Command*` (emacs adds an incremental suffix when it's asked to create more than one).

To see the list of other available display options, type `C-h f display-buffer` and look for the list of "action functions".

```
;; Buffers that I don't want popping up by default
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist
  '("\\*Async Shell Command\\*.*" display-buffer-no-window))
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to check out `async-start-process` (from `emacs-async`):

```
(async-start-process "name" "cmd" nil "arg1" "arg2)
```

That nil argument is the place for a function to run when it's done.

Whilst emacs-async is an external package it's highly likely you have it as a dependency if you've installed much from MELPA and it makes what you want very easy.