# Async shell process buffer always clobbers window arrangement

Tags: window, shell, async

I frequently launch external programs from emacs using `M-!`, such as Firefox or Evince, etc. Whenever I do, a buffer pops up full of results for the process, which clobbers whatever else I've got going on in terms of windows arrangement.

Is there a way to bury such buffers by default, so that I don't have to see them unless I decide to go looking for them?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I run an async process in the background without popping up a buffer?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/299/how-can-i-run-an-async-process-in-the-background-without-popping-up-a-buffer)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Since mention that the command is running asynchronously I am assuming you mean the command `async-shell-command` bound to <kbd>M-&</kbd>. You can follow the advice in documentation of `async-shell-command` (you can read it by doing <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>f</kbd>`async-shell-command`<kbd>RET</kbd>) customize `display-buffer-alist` as follows

```
(add-to-list 'display-buffer-alist (cons "\\*Async Shell Command\\*.*" (cons #'display-buffer-no-window nil)))
```

Now the buffer used by the command to display output will never be shown.

Comment: This works beautifully, thank you. Additionally, I didn't know about `M-&` either. I was using `M-!` and then manually adding the `&` to the command I passed to the shell.

Answer (score 4):

Emacs has a general-purpose facility to prevent any unintentional (or indeed intentional) window configuration changes from causing problems.

Add `(winner-mode 1)` to your init file. Then when something messes up your windows, use <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd><left></kbd> (`winner-undo`) to restore them. You can use it repeatedly to undo multiple window configuration changes. <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd><right></kbd> (`winner-redo`) returns you to the most recent configuration.

Comment: Yes, I am a very enthusiastic user of Winner Mode!

Answer (score 4):

Here's my configuration. It should work great if you're on Linux.

```
(require 'dired-aux)

(defvar dired-filelist-cmd
  '(("vlc" "-L")))

(defun dired-start-process (cmd &optional file-list)
  (interactive
   (let ((files (dired-get-marked-files t current-prefix-arg)))
     (list
      (dired-read-shell-command "& on %s: " current-prefix-arg files)
      files)))
  (start-process
   cmd nil shell-file-name
   shell-command-switch
   (format "nohup 1>/dev/null 2>/dev/null %s \"%s\""
           (if (> (length file-list) 1)
               (format "%s %s" cmd
                       (cadr (assoc cmd dired-filelist-cmd)))
             cmd)
           (mapconcat #'expand-file-name file-list "\" \""))))

(define-key dired-mode-map "r" 'dired-start-process)
```

Not only will it hide those pesky buffers when you e.g. open a pdf file from `dired`,
Evince *will persist* even if you close Emacs.
There's also a small customization for queuing up marked video files for a vlc playlist.

Answer (score 2):

You can suppress that window for a single command instead of globally using `let`

```
(let ((display-buffer-alist
       (cons (cons "\\*Async Shell Command\\*.*"
                   (cons #'display-buffer-no-window nil))
             display-buffer-alist))) ;; suppress async shell command window
  (async-shell-command command))
```

Comment: I suggest `(cons NEWTHING display-buffer-alist)` instead of `(list NEWTHING)` so as not to completely inhibit the original alist.

Comment: Good suggestion, implemented it.