# Define the behaviour of help window?

Tags: window, help, window-splitting, help-mode

When I'm looking for documentation or information, I press <kbd>C-h</kbd> and then <kbd>f</kbd> or <kbd>k</kbd> or anything else. Then a help window will pop up.

I was wondering if I could configure the help window, that he will pop up on the bottom, instead on right and with much smaller window?
Is there any property/variable to manage this behaviour? If this is not specificed for the help-mode, then I might develop a package for that.

Comment: Does it work to customize `display-buffer-alist` for buffers called `*Help*` to use the function `display-buffer-at-bottom` ([Action Functions for `display-buffer`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Display-Action-Functions.html))?

Comment: There are a couple of exceptions, but the primary function responsible for the behavior the original poster wishes to modify is `temp-buffer-window-show` within `window.el`.  As can be seen by examining the function, the `temp-buffer-resize-mode` is taken into consideration if it is active -- thus, look at the doc-string for that minor-mode also.  It is possible to customize the `display-buffer-alist` since `temp-buffer-window-show` calls `display-buffer`, but I prefer to use a scalpel instead of a machete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @Krill in comments you can use `display-buffer-alist` to control the display of buffers, for some explanation/examples look at the following questions

- [How to control in which window a buffer is displayed?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/721/how-to-control-in-which-window-a-buffer-is-displayed/724#724)
- [Async shell process buffer always clobbers window arrangement](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5553/async-shell-process-buffer-always-clobbers-window-arrangement/5554#5554)

However that is a bit low level if all you want is to set the position of a buffer or specify it height. I know of two libraries that provide high level APIs for such customizations

1) [popwin-el](https://github.com/m2ym/popwin-el)

Using popwin you could do the following to keep help-mode buffers at   bottom

```el
(add-to-list popwin:special-display-config '(help-mode 0.5 :position below))
```

2) [shackle](https://github.com/wasamasa/shackle)

To keep the help-mode buffers at bottom using shackle you can do the following

```el
(add-to-list 'shackle-rules '(help-mode :align below))
```

Comment: Thanks Iqbal for your reply, I never thought of adding modes to popwin. And with your reply I discovered Shackle, which I prefer, because it didn't conflict with `helm-for-files` window with adding a new window on top of it. Your answer really helped me, thanks for that.

Comment: @ReneFroger, glad I could help!